# How can I use a column named _id from a dashDB table?

Tags: sql, cloudant, dashdb, warehouse

I have a database in Cloudant where the document ID is `_id`.

After replicating this data from Cloudant to dashDB I have 2 separate tables that I want to join using this `_id` column. In Run SQL I tried the below, but this would not run. What am I missing here? Do I need to replace the column name `_id` to something without an underscore?

```
select m.title, m.year, g.value 
from MOVIES m
inner join MOVIES_GENRE g on m._ID = g._ID;
```

Comment: Are you receiving a specific error? If you suspect it is the column name `_id`, you could try putting double-quotes around it to indicate that it is an object name: `inner join MOVIES_GENRE g on m."_ID" = g."_ID";` If possible though, renaming those columns to a more standard format would be advisable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR**: As @gmiley points out the issue is caused by the `_ID` column name, which is not an ordinary identifier (see definition below) and therefore needs to be enclosed in double quotes `"_ID"` or single quotes `'_ID'` in your SQL statements.

```
select m.title, m.year, g.value 
from MOVIES m
inner join MOVIES_GENRE g on m."_ID" = g."_ID";
```

Unlike ordinary identifiers *quoted identifiers are case sensitive* (`"_id"` is not identical to `"_ID"` whereas `title` is identical to `TITLE`). If you were to specify `"_id"` in your statement an error would be raised indicating that the column wasn't found.

Since you've mentioned that you've used the [Cloudant warehousing process](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/guides/warehousing.html#data-warehousing) to populate your DashDB tables it's probably worth mentioning that property names are upper-cased when the DDL is generated during the schema discovery.

Example: The content of JSON documents with this structure

```
 {
  "_id": "000018723bdb4f2b06f830f676cfafd6",
  "_rev": "1-91f98642f125315b929be5b5436530e7",
  "date_received": "2016-12-04T17:46:47.090Z",
  ...
 }
```

will be mapped to three columns:

- `_ID` of type  `VARCHAR(...)`
- `_REV` of type `VARCHAR(...)`
- `DATE_RECEIVED` of type ...
- ...

Hope this helps!

---

From the [DB2 SQL reference](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ps/products/db2/info/vr105/pdf/en_US/DB2SQLRefVol1-db2s1e1051.pdf):

> An *ordinary identifier* is an uppercase letter followed by zero or more characters, each of which is an uppercase letter, a digit, or the underscore character. Note that lowercase letters can be used when specifying an ordinary identifier, but they are converted to uppercase when processed. An ordinary identifier should not be a reserved word.
>
> Examples: `WKLYSAL` `WKLY_SAL`
>
> A *delimited identifier* is a sequence of one or more characters enclosed by
>   double quotation marks. Leading blanks in the sequence are significant.
>   Trailing blanks in the sequence are not significant, although they are stored
>   with the identifier. Two consecutive quotation marks are used to represent
>   one quotation mark within the delimited identifier. In this way an identifier
>   can include lowercase letters.
>
> Examples:
>   `"WKLY_SAL"`     `"WKLY SAL"`     `"UNION"`     `"wkly_sal"`